# BlackBerry external jar

Tags: blackberry, java-me, build

I am using JDom jar and I want to add to my blackberry project. I am using eclipse plugins for blacberry. while building blackberry app from eclipse the error is displayed on the console as

```
"JDOMAbout$info:error!missing stack map @label.... "
```

rapc falied for the project along with this several warnings are also displayed ...so any body have came across this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877428/better-approach-for-xml-creation-in-blackberry

Answer (score 1):

The stack map is part of what's generated when a jar file is [preverified](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/J2ME_Programming/MIDlet_Preverify).  Sounds like your jar is not J2ME ready.  Assuming it's compatible with J2ME, the standard way is to create a .cod file from the .jar, and [reference that in your project](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Compile_a_JAR_file_into_a_BlackBerry_Library.html?nodeid=801017&vernum=0).  Unfortunately you can't do that with the Eclipse plugin, but once you have the .cod, you can reference it in your Eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Blackberry archive or library project (or whatever it's called) and add your library to that, then reference it from your application project. You may or may not have to use the Blackberry JDE to do some hackery with the jdp file as well, but I can assure it works in Eclipse. We had the kSOAP library included in ours and Eclipse would 'build' it with rapc and generate the proper files (you sort of have to do it manually, by telling the project to build).

I unfortunately don't have an environment to check things right now, but the basic idea was have a second project, include the jar, and then reference that.

All that, and the jar has to be J2ME compatible.

Comment: If possible can u plz send me a link for steps to include external jar in eclipse as it didnt work for me using the standard procedure .also  in JDE  it didnt worked with the standard steps provided on line .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can find something useful and more J2ME friendly in kDom package of [kXML project](http://kxml.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial: How To Use 3rd Party Libraries in your Applications](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?board.id=java_dev&message.id=22441)