# How to Overwrite XML File in Blackberry?

Tags: xml, blackberry

I want to overwrite an XML File that is stored in Project's Resource folder.

How would I do that?

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877428/better-approach-for-xml-creation-in-blackberry

Comment: Good link user705635, lots of useful information there. But to answer the original question, a resource is bundled in the COD file so I believe it is imutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the file contents inside of your application cod file.

On the first run your application can [create an external xml file](http://blackberry-tips-bikas.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-read-write-and-copy-file-in.html) using stored xml information stored in cod file. And after that change it when necessary.

Comment: Thanks Rafael But I want to Overwrite XML that already keep in resource folder .In my app xml keep in resource folder & when app start it check for updated xml if that xml updated than overwrite xml in resource folder