# Write the Xml document to a file to save  Changes in Blackberry

Tags: file, blackberry, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse Xml in Blackberry. I copied the xml to the SD card. I tried this code and I succeeded. I tried to insert new tags (Nodes) to the xml and it works but they are added to the end of the file but I don't know if it is the best way to do that, but how can I write the Xml document to the file to save the changes??

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory= DocumentBuilderFactory. newInstance(); 
 DocumentBuilder docBuilder= docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 docBuilder.isValidating();
 doc = docBuilder.parse(conn.openInputStream());
 InsertBlock(doc);
 doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
 NodeList list=doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
 node=new String();
 element = new String();

 for (int i=0;i<list.getLength();i++){
      Node value=list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0);
      node=list.item(i).getNodeName();
      element=value.getNodeValue();
 }
```

And for inserting new Nodes :

```
Node emp=myDocument.createElement("Emp");
Text NodeText = myDocument.createTextNode("DD");
emp.appendChild(NodeText);
myDocument.appendChild(emp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert new node(s) you should use `Node#insertBefore()` instead of `Node#appendChild()`. Check documentation [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#insertBefore%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29).

Replace

```
Node emp=myDocument.createElement("Emp");
Text NodeText = myDocument.createTextNode("DD");
emp.appendChild(NodeText);
myDocument.appendChild(emp);
```

with

```
Node emp=myDocument.createElement("Emp");
Text NodeText = myDocument.createTextNode("DD");
emp.appendChild(NodeText); 
myDocument.insertBefore(emp, someExistingNode);
```

Where **someExistingNode** is the `Node` (probably `Element`) before which you want to add your new `Node` **emp**.

**Edit 1:** How to write XML to file

```
try {
    String filePath = "file:///store/home/user/XmlFile.xml";
    FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(filePath, Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (!fc.exists()) {
        fc.create();  // create the file if it doesn't exist
    } else {
        fc.truncate(0); // truncate the file if it exists
    }

    OutputStream os = fc.openOutputStream();
    XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(os);
    xmlWriter.setPrettyPrint();
    DOMInternalRepresentation.parse(myDocument, xmlWriter);
    os.close();
    fc.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // Place exception handling code here
}
```

**Edit 2:** Added code sample for node insertion and XML-to-file writing

```
try {
    // Creating document
    Document myDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

    Element parentElement = myDocument.createElement("parentTag");

    // create first element and append it to parent
    Element firstElement = myDocument.createElement("firstElement");
    firstElement.appendChild(myDocument.createTextNode("1"));
    parentElement.appendChild(firstElement);

    // create third element and append it to parent
    Element thirdElement = myDocument.createElement("thirdElement");
    thirdElement.appendChild(myDocument.createTextNode("3"));
    parentElement.appendChild(thirdElement);

    // create second element and insert it between first and third elements
    Element secondElement = myDocument.createElement("secondElement");
    secondElement.appendChild(myDocument.createTextNode("2"));
    parentElement.insertBefore(secondElement, thirdElement);

    myDocument.appendChild(parentElement);

    // Writing document to file
    String filePath = "file:///store/home/user/XmlFile.xml";
    FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(filePath, Connector.READ_WRITE);
    if (!fc.exists()) {
        fc.create();  // create the file if it doesn't exist
    } else {
        fc.truncate(0); // truncate the file if it exists
    }

    OutputStream os = fc.openOutputStream();
    XMLWriter xmlWriter = new XMLWriter(os);
    xmlWriter.setPrettyPrint();
    DOMInternalRepresentation.parse(myDocument, xmlWriter);
    os.close();
    fc.close();            

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/877428/396949) regarding XML creation on BlackBerry.

Comment: Thank you MrVincenzo..Your answer helped me alot..:)

Comment: You welcome @Reham. You can delete `Node`s with `Node#removeChild()` method. For example, you can call `parentElement.removeChild(firstElement);` to remove the **firstElement** in my sample code.

Comment: this code works if i create a new node and delete it,
but how can i use the remove method if i want to delete an existing node in my xml file?

Comment: @Reham Parse the XML into a `Document`, find the node you want to remove, remove it with `removeChild()` and write the document back to file again. AFAIK, this is the only way to modify the XML document when using the `Document` class. You can use the `getParentNode()` method to retrieve the node's parent node.

Comment: try{
       
        Node parentElement = myDocument.getParentNode();
           Node firstElement = parentElement.getFirstChild();
           parentElement.removeChild(firstElement);
       }
       catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());

i tried this and i'm getting Null Exception

  }

Comment: `myDocument.getParentNode()` returns `null`, thus NullPointerException is thrown later. Replace it with `myDocument.getFirstChild()`.

Comment: @MrVincenzo See my ques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361763/read-write-and-create-local-xml-file . i have one xml file which i i have a set to SDCard. i have read this xml successfully. there is no issue upto yet but now i want to add more node in this xml and i want reflect this in my existing xml file. i have tried the below code as per your suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361763/read-write-and-create-local-xml-file but getting DOMException . please guide me